# PHP secured code with SHA1 and AES256

Tags: php, hash, sha1

I have one issue, that I'm not able to solve...

Instructions:

1. Create hash with SHA1 from string
2. Take first 16 bytes from string and encode them with AES256 and KEY
3. You get 16 bytes signature. You have to convert this signature to 32-bytes string, which represent signature in hexadecimal

My function:

```
public function GetSign($str) {
                $strSIGN = sha1($str, true);
                $strSIGN = substr($strSIGN, 0, 16);


                $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
                $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
                mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::KEY, $iv);

                $strSIGN = mcrypt_generic($td, substr($strSIGN, 0, 16));
                mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
                mcrypt_module_close($td);  

                $strSIGNhex = '';

                for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($strSIGN); $i++)
                {
                       $ord = ord($strSIGN[$i]);
                       $hexCode = dechex($ord);    

                      $strSIGNhex .= ((strlen($hexCode) == 1) ? '0' : '') . $hexCode;
                }

                return $strSIGNhex;
        }
```

But the result is incorrect...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the result is incorrect? AES256 returns different values based on the iv, which is in your case random.

Its completely acceptable to have different signatures after different executions - the only requirement is, you can verify, that the output is correct.

Comment: Yes result is for sure incorrect. I really don't understand the part of code with IV, I used solution I found... The functions should generate the same result also if you refresh page, so maybe i should change something in this part?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem this instructions should solve. As far as i understand, you want to generate a signature, using a hash and a key. This problem is normally solved with a [HMAC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).

With your code you won't be able to recreate the signature to do a verification, because you used the CBC mode with an IV (initialisation vector). This is actually a good thing, but you would have to store the IV too, so you could use the same IV to encrypt another string and do the verification. Of course storing the IV would result in a much longer string than 16 bytes.

Either you use the ECB mode, which doesn't need an IV, or you use the HMAC which is made for such situations.

Comment: Can you show me example with HMAC? It's not necessary to use IV, I only used solution i found...

Comment: @general666 - An example could look like that `hash_hmac('sha1', $str, self::KEY)`. The output looks like the hex representation of an SHA-1 hash, but the key is safely mixed in.